# Find column where sum is meeting condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

A have a sheet with resources and week together with availabilty per week (hours). Like this.

```
Resource 1225 1226 1227 ... 1252
.NET     30   30   15   ... 30
Java     40   40   40   ... 40
```

In another table i´ve got his data

```
Resource PlannedHours StartWeek EndWeek AvailableHours Diff ActualEndWeek
.NET     326          1225      1242    400            76   ?    
Java     100          1225      1242    400            300  ?
```

Planned hours comes from hours project/ticket system, start and end week is entered manually. Availible hours and diff is calculated from the first table.

I´ve solved everything but the last column where I need help. How can a find the week when the availible resources in the first table sums up and is big enough to cover the planned hours. I need that column and put the week in actualendweek column?

Answer (score 0):

```
Function LeastFactors(MyArray As Range, Goal As Double) As Integer
Dim RunningTotal As Double
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To MyArray.Count
    RunningTotal = RunningTotal + WorksheetFunction.Large(MyArray, i)
    If RunningTotal >= Goal Then
        LeastFactors = i
        Exit For
    Else
        LeastFactors = 0
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

use would be `=LeastFactors(Sheet1!B2:B40,Sheet2!B2)` to give you how many weeks you would need. It will return zero if it can't find an answer